# pgsql can connect, pgadmin cannot

Tags: debian, psql, postgresql

We want only 1 role owning 1 database, Domain-unix Socket, no password

```
postgres@luciol-essai:~$ more /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf | grep jppstphp
local   essais_php  jppstphp                       trust
postgres@luciol-essai:~$
```

Success with psql :

```
envol@luciol-essai:~$ psql -U jppstphp essais_php
psql (8.4.15)
essais_php=>
```

Failure with pgadmin3 :

This is the error.

```
Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  authentification Ident ?chou?e pour l'utilisateur << jppstphp >>
```

Comment: What are the connection parameters you're using with pgadmin3?  Are you using the socket or the 5432 port to localhost?

Comment: pgadmin 1.10.5, for host, trying empty, or trying path to lock 5432, suppressing tcp port inhibit validate button !

Comment: obviously pgadmin succed with habilitation host    essais_php jppstphp 127.0.0.1/32       trust

Comment: using `more` there is completely unnecessary, it's like using `cat file | command`. Just use `grep term filename`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PgAdmin-III is being told to connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, so it's using TCP/IP, wheras psql isn't being given a host specification so it's using UNIX sockets (`local`).

Leave the host name field in pgadmin3 blank, or add another `pg_hba.conf` entry for `host essais_php  jppstphp 127.0.0.1/32 trust`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your whole `pg_hba.conf` file, the order of directives is important.  I guess you kept the default line in it:

```
local   all         all                               ident
```

If this line is present before your specific line about `jppstphp`, the postgresql server will first try to identify you from your UNIX username, which seems to be `envol`.  This will fail because you try to connect as postgres user/role `jppstphp`.

If my assumption is correct, removing the above line (and possibly the similar entry with `md5` password authentication) or placing your `jppstphp` line before it should allow you to connect through the local socket.

To connect through the local socket, leaving the host field blank, like you did, is all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with psql via command line connecting and pgAdmin not connecting on RDS with AWS.  I did have my RDS set to Publicly Accessible. I made sure my ACL and security groups were wide open and still problem so, I did the following:
`sudo find . -name *.conf`
then `sudo nano ./data/pg_hba.conf`
then added to top of directives in pg_hba.conf file `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`
and pgAdmin automatically logged me in.

As a side note, my RDS was in my default VPC.  I had an identical RDS instance in my non-default VPC with identical security group, ACL and security group settings to my default VPC and I could not get it to work.  Not sure why but, that's for another day.